# Merge json files by key using pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark

Json file is in the following format:-

```
**Input-** 

{'key-a' : [{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'},{'key1':'value3', 'key2':'value4'}...], 
'key-b':'value-b', 
'key-c':'value-c'},
{'key-a' : [{'key1':'value5', 'key2':'value6'},{'key1':'value7', 'key2':'value8'}...], 
'key-b':'value-b', 
'key-c':'value-c'}
```

I need to combine the data to merge all the values of 'key-a' and return a single json object as output:

```
**Output-** 
{'key-a' : 
[{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'},
{'key1':'value3', 'key2':'value4'},
{'key1':'value5', 'key2':'value6'},
{'key1':'value7', 'key2':'value8'}...], 
'key-b':'value-b', 
'key-c':'value-c'}
```

The data is loaded in a pyspark dataframe with the following schema:-

```
**Schema:**

key-a
|-- key1: string (nullable= false)
|-- key2: string (nullable= true)
key-b: string (nullable= true)
key-c: string (nullable= false)
```

I have tried using the `groupbykey` function but when I try to `Show()` the output, I get the following error: "`groupeddata` object has no attribute 'show' pyspark".

How to achieve the above transformation?

PFA- [Error received when trying below answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmlQn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a working solution for you -

**# Create the dataframe here**

```
df_new = spark.createDataFrame([(str({"key-a":[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}, {"key1": "value3", "key2": "value4"}], "key-b" :"value-b"})), (str({"key-a":[{"key1":"value5","key2":"value6"}, {"key1": "value7", "key2": "value8"}], "key-b" :"value-b"}))],T.StringType())
df_new.show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{'key-a': [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key1': 'value3', 'key2': 'value4'}], 'key-b': 'value-b'}|
|{'key-a': [{'key1': 'value5', 'key2': 'value6'}, {'key1': 'value7', 'key2': 'value8'}], 'key-b': 'value-b'}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Use **`from_json`** with correct schema to valuate the column first -**
The idea here is to get the keys of the json in a column and then use **`groupBy`**

```
df = df_new.withColumn('col', F.from_json("value",T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType())))
df = df.select("col", F.explode("col").alias("x", "y"))
df.select("x", "y").show(truncate=False)
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|x    |y                                                                    |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|key-a|[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value3","key2":"value4"}]|
|key-b|value-b                                                              |
|key-a|[{"key1":"value5","key2":"value6"},{"key1":"value7","key2":"value8"}]|
|key-b|value-b                                                              |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Logic Here-**
**We have created a dummy column for the sake of grouping**

```
df_grp = df.groupBy("x").agg(F.collect_set("y").alias("y"))
df_grp = df_grp.withColumn("y", F.col("y").cast(T.StringType()))
df_grp = df_grp.withColumn("array", F.array("x", "y"))
df_grp = df_grp.withColumn("dummy_col", F.lit("1"))
df_grp = df_grp.groupBy("dummy_col").agg(F.collect_set("array"))
df_grp.show(truncate=False)

+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|dummy_col|collect_set(array)                                                                                                                                                           |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1        |[[key-a, [[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value3","key2":"value4"}], [{"key1":"value5","key2":"value6"},{"key1":"value7","key2":"value8"}]]], [key-b, [value-b]]]|
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: It is giving syntax error in line - df_grp = df.groupBy("x").agg(F.collect_set("y").alias("y"))

Comment: can u post the error ? it should not be ..it's a tested code

Comment: I have attached the error screenshot in the question above

Comment: check the syntax correctly .. Looks like something else is there .. I might need to see the full code in order to debug more .. Meanwhile I will really appreciate if you  could help approve and upvote if the solution / approach helped you ..

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using the groupbykey function but when I try to Show() the output, I get the following error: "groupeddata object has no attribute 'show' pyspark".

*This was giving trouble because you did not use any aggregate function in the* **`groupBy`** *clause.*